# Error while Recovering a WiredTiger collection from a corrupt MongoDB installation

Tags: linux, mongodb, wiredtiger

We have implemented MongoDB master-slave replication and database got deleted.

We restored deleted files from Mongo data directory using `extundelete` command.

[Undelete Blog](https://github.com/RIKSOF/development/wiki/Restoring-deleted-files-on-Linux) https://github.com/RIKSOF/development/wiki/Restoring-deleted-files-on-Linux

We wanted to restore at least one collection for which we got the WT (wired timer) file. We are trying to restore that file using the following commands and we are getting the following errors

[Recovering a WiredTiger collection from a corrupt MongoDB installation](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/)

`wget http://source.wiredtiger.com/releases/wiredtiger-2.7.0.tar.bz2
tar xvf wiredtiger-2.7.0.tar.bz2
cd wiredtiger-2.7.0
sudo apt-get install libsnappy-dev build-essential
./configure --enable-snappy
make`

`./wt -v -h ../mongo-bak -C "extensions=[./ext/compressors/snappy/.libs/libwiredtiger_snappy.so]" -R salvage collection-2657--1723320556100349955.wt`

Error -

`./wt -v -h ../mongo-bak -C "extensions=[./ext/compressors/snappy/.libs/libwiredtiger_snappy.so]" -R salvage collection-246--7553069514495955510.wt
[1488888117:36780][13536:0x7f7b633cd740], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: read checksum error for 4096B block at offset 12288: block header checksum of 1955562709 doesn't match expected checksum of 3146787951
[1488888117:36809][13536:0x7f7b633cd740], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: WiredTiger.wt: encountered an illegal file format or internal value
[1488888117:36817][13536:0x7f7b633cd740], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
lt-wt: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic`

Answer (score 5):

This could be related to corrupted `.wt` files (e.g. `WiredTiger.wt`/`WiredTiger.turtle`) as per [SERVER-31076](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31076) bug report.

Try to run repair on all databases by the following command:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```

Also make sure all `data/db` files have the right read and write permission.

Comment: I have an issue when i tried to do  mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair 
 WT_TRY_SALVAGE: database corruption detected
Do you have an idea of how to fix it? (mongo 4.0) My mongo is broken since disk space failure ....)

Comment: If `mongod --repair` didn't help, I'm not sure, it's better if you can ask another question with the relevant error.

Comment: Did the trick for me. The logs contained errors related to WireTiger and checksum mismatch.

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue. It just try to run the same files, and obviously the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had recovered mac from Time Machine. I had mongodb installed via brew install. When I started mongo, the service did not start cleanly.

```
vi /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
enter code here
2020-01-30T17:06:10.655-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1580421970:655376][62181:0x112233dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __wt_block_read_off, 283: WiredTiger.wt: read checksum error for 4096B block at offset 12288: block header checksum of 0x325e318 doesn't match expected checksum of 0x65ef0e12 Raw: [1580421970:655376][62181:0x112233dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __wt_block_read_off, 283: WiredTiger.wt: read checksum error for 4096B block at offset 12288: block header checksum of 0x325e318 doesn't match expected checksum of 0x65ef0e12
```

What I saw was that because of a corrupt mongodb collection. 
So, I ran the cleanup command for the brew install, which has the db in a different location.

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb

    2020-01-30T17:06:11.741-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify failed on uri table:collection-12--8361386101775862971. Running a salvage operation.
2020-01-30T17:06:11.745-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection wlchat.jobs
2020-01-30T17:06:11.765-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger progress WT_SESSION.verify 100
2020-01-30T17:06:11.769-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger progress WT_SESSION.verify 200
2020-01-30T17:06:11.774-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger progress WT_SESSION.verify 300
2020-01-30T17:06:11.783-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger progress WT_SESSION.verify 400
2020-01-30T17:06:11.789-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger progress WT_SESSION.verify 500
2020-01-30T17:06:11.793-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger progress WT_SESSION.verify 600
2020-01-30T17:06:11.795-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-10--8361386101775862971. Not salvaging.
2020-01-30T17:06:11.795-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection wlchat.SovrenJobs
2020-01-30T17:06:11.801-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-0-8794251073515214768. Not salvaging.
2020-01-30T17:06:11.814-0500 I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: starting on wlchat.users properties: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "wlchat.users" } using method: Foreground
```

and restart mongodb-community

```
brew services restart mongodb-community.
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

Things are back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and trying a lot of way to resolve but not reached to successfully.

I am currently using 5.0.1 mongodb standalone version,

- removed currently installed mongodb ( 5.0.1 )
- installed latest version (  6.0 )

and reapaired all corrupted *.wt file and verified.

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```